# Reusable component emitting same value in component when use multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, mat-select

I have created Angular reusable material multi select options as in below. When I used this reusable component in app.ts multiple times, both mat-reusable-select values are overwriting each other. How I can get both values in app.ts? What I have missed?

**mat-reusable-select.html**

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="none"
                floatLabel="never">
    <mat-select [formControl]="multiSelectheckboxFormControl"
                (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
                placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
                #selection
                multiple>
        <mat-select-trigger class="mat-select-trigger">
            {{selection.value ? selection.value.length : ''}}
            <span *ngIf="multiSelectheckboxFormControl.value?.length >= 1">
                {{placeholder}}
            </span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of data"
                    color="primary"
                    [value]="item.name">{{item.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**mat-reusable-select.ts**

```js
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() data: any;
  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter<MatSelectChange>();

  multiSelectheckboxFormControl = new FormControl();

  onSelectionChange(event: MatSelectChange): any {
    this.selectionChange.emit(event.value);
  }
```

**app.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-reusable-select [data]="products | async"
  [placeholder]="'Products'"
  (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
  </mat-reusable-select>

  <mat-reusable-select [data]="sales | async"
  [placeholder]="'Sales'"
  (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
  </mat-reusable-select>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**app.ts**

```js
onSelectionChange(event: string[]) {
  // output: ['prod1', 'product]
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Could not understand the question very well, but if you are referring to the fact that both reusable components are referring to the same onSelectionChange event then why not you write different methods for both mat-reusable-select components ?

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways.

1- to make separate function for each `<mat-reusable-select></mat-reusable-select>`

2- to modify the current function `onSelectionChange(event)` to have two parameters, one for the `event` and another one for the source `src`.

I prefer the 2nd solution and it goes as follows:

```
onSelectionChange(event: string[], src: string) {
   if (src === 'firstReusableSelect') {
      this.firstReusableSelection = event;
   } else if (src === 'secondReusableSelect') {
      this.secondReusableSelection = event;
   }
}
```

in your template, modify the event binding:

```
<mat-reusable-select [data]="products | async"
   [placeholder]="'Products'"
   (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event, 'firstReusableSelection')">
</mat-reusable-select>

<mat-reusable-select [data]="sales | async"
   [placeholder]="'Sales'"
   (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event, 'secondReusableSelection')">
</mat-reusable-select>
```

and this way you get two properties `firstReusableSelection` & `secondReusableSelection` containing the selection from both reusable components without overwriting each other.

I hope this is what you are looking for.